# invoke workspace variable in python script

Tags: python, global-variables, spyder, variable-assignment

I have a script that takes quite some time to calculate some data. I then want to code a new script that handles these data. I have tried to find a way to invoke variables and arrays from my workspace in spyder in to a new script. something like
array1=fromlocalworkspace.get.array2

I haven't yet found a way that this can be done.
I realize that there are other ways to go about this but I want to avoid creating the data everytime I want to try something new.

I can access the workspace variable and input them into a local function through the terminal however this isn't really what I am looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check my answer on the question I referenced above. It has the instructions you need to do what you want.